# How to remove tabs in product page in magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, tabs, product-page

I want to remove the review tab and tags tab from the product page in magento 1.7.0.2. But I am not able to find a correct solution.

Thanks.

Comment: give a screen shot?

Answer (score 3):

Sai,kumar,you can remove any block using xml code ***`<remove name="blockNameAtXml"/>`***
As product default  handler is 
then you can remove the block using below code:

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="product.info">
<remove name="product.reviews" />
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```